# How to package icons on Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am developing a project in Eclipse RCP. Everything is working fine, expect the icons. I am able to get the icons when I am executing the code. But when I package it as a product, the icons are inside the jar file and I get a file not found exception when I run the executable. How do package icons required for my app for my eclipse RCP.

Regards,

Comment: How are you loading the icons in your code? Also can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

did you had icons folder in build.xml?

Comment: No idea. Can you just help me out in that

Comment: open plugin.xml using Plug-In Manifest Editor, go to Build tab and check the icons folder

Answer (score 1):

try defining icon in your product definition

```
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="org.eclipsercp.hyperbola.application"
            name="Hyperbola Chat Client">
         <property
               name="aboutImage"
               value="icons/about.gif"/>
         <property
               name="aboutText"
               value="%aboutText"/>
         <property
               name="windowImages"
               value="icons/online.gif"/>
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="Hyperbola Chat Client">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
```